# Class metadata in Hibernate 6 using AbstractEntityPersister

Tags: hibernate-6.x

I'm in the process of migration from Hibernate 5.6 to 6.2. I have a utility class that via a deprecated call to

```java
entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(clazz)
```

was obtaining an instance of `AbstractEntityPersister` with which I had access to methods like:

1. toColumns
2. getPropertyNames
3. getPropertyColumnNames
4. getPropertyNullability
5. getIdentifier
6. getPropertyValue

What is the proper way to have access to these methods in Hibernate 6? Is there another recommended API alternative to **all** these methods?

What I tried was working with `entityManager.getMetamodel().managedType(clazz)` but I only had partial success, or access to methods that seem to only help me do my own implementation of the needed methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked for me

```
AbstractEntityPersister persister = ((AbstractEntityPersister) ((MappingMetamodel) sessionFactory.getMetamodel()).getEntityDescriptor(clazz));
```

Comment: What I found was
```(AbstractEntityPersister)((JpaMetamodelImplementor)entityManager.getMetamodel()).getMappingMetamodel().findEntityDescriptor(clazz)``` 
but didn't yet have the chance to test it since I'm in the middle of migrating. Your solution seems very similar with the extra confirmation that it worked for you. So thanks a lot!

Comment: I discovered and tested that one could use `sessionFactory.getRuntimeMetamodels()`  to have access to both the mapping metamodel (`sessionFactory.getRuntimeMetamodels().getMappingMetamodel()` from my question) and the metamodel (`sessionFactory.getRuntimeMetamodels().getJpaMetamodel()`) which I also needed but does not appear in my question.

More directly to my question I used: `(AbstractEntityPersister)((SessionFactoryImplementor)sessionFactory).getRuntimeMetamodels().getMappingMetamodel().findEntityDescriptor(clazz)`